# Can't import OpenEXR under python2.7

Tags: python, openexr

Import Error /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenEXR.so: undefined symbol.

I meet this error after install OpenEXR-1.3.0 OR 1.2.0.

I used pip install OpenEXR for installation.

Can anyone help me?